# Package installation errors

Tags: 12.04, error-handling

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, but when I try to install a package e.g. vim, aptitude, synaptic etc, it shows this error message:

```
E: package "vim" has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try installing vim again using `sudo apt-get install vim`